# How to send OTP via email for password reset in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a react native application using firebase for user authentication. I know that it supports sending emails for account verification and password reset, but that is sent with a link.

Is there a way to send an OTP via email, which user can enter in my app and reset the password?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to send OTP to email using the firebase authentication
Try using phone no. to receive OTP